# How to insert unicode string into sql server using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, unicode

Hi have a sql string where want insert data to sql server , how to use `N` when i add values like @value

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into News (News,title) values (@news,@title)", conn);
string news = TextBox1.Text;
string title = TextBox2.Text;

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"news", news);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"title", title);
```

Comment: You don't need to use `N`.

Comment: Hpw do it ? i add non english string

Comment: Do you have tried without `N`?

Comment: What datatype are your columns in the `News` table?

Answer (score 3):

Code seems fine - and no, you don't need to use the `N` prefix anywhere in such a scenario (only when you're writing a **string literal** in e.g. Management Studio).

The only thing that *might* be something to look into is explicitly specifying the parameter types:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@news", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = news;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@title", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Value = title;
```

but usually, ADO.NET is pretty good at guessing the right datatype, especially since .NET strings *are* in fact Unicode already.